# Redirecting for child routes in ZF2 throws an error

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

I've have an problem to redirect on child routes in zend framework 2. I can access the controller and action but while redirecting it throws me an error missing parameter "id".

```
  'admin' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/admin[/][:action][/:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                     'child_routes' => array(
                        'settings' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'may_terminate' => true,
                            'options' => array(
                                'route'    => '/general[/][:action][/][:id]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Settings\General',
                                    'action'     => 'index',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

I have given redirect to route like below,

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/settings');
```

But it throws an error,

```
Missing parameter "id"
```

Answer (score 3):

as the error message implies you need to add the "id" parameter. You can redirect with a parameter like so.

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin', array('action'=>'settings', 'id' => $id));
```

You did not show us your Controller action's but I assume 'settings' is a action within your admin module.

At this point I cannot really see what kind of id the admin/settings function need's might aswell just try to add a 0 or 1 to try the route at first for testing purposes.

Comment: Id is optional one in the route. I really do not use Id for this.

Comment: can you try redirecting to return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin', array('action'=>'settings'));

Comment: Its working but i have to redirect back to /admin/settings/general. But that general/ is where i written directly into the route. How to do this?

Comment: it worked by using this "return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin',array('action' => 'settings','id'=> 'general'));" but i don't know why?

Comment: can you show us the controller? Or do you have some param route match like this $id $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id'); in your controller? You may also check the documentation for zf2 routing again. You have to use redirect differently on route (segments/literals/regex/query).

Answer (score 2):

The route matching method doesn't seem to 'consume' the *parent node* of the route.

Changing the child route to include the */admin* part of the *grammar* to

> /admin/settings/general[/][:action][/][:id]

or

> /admin/settings[/][:action][/][:id]

should allow `$this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/settings');` to work.